# Pythonのパッケージyoutube_dlで、DownloadErrorが発生する。

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

Pythonで、Youtube動画をダウンロードするパッケージ(youtube_dl)を利用すると、以下のエラーが発生します。数か月前に、同じ呼出し方法で実行したときは、正しく動作していたのですが、サポートされなくなってしまったということでしょうか。

ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

以下は、呼出し方法です。

```
import youtube_dl
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s'}) as youtube:
    youtube.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNltA11uim4'])
```

インストール方法は以下です。

```
!pip3 install --upgrade --user youtube_dl
```

実行した結果、発生したエラーは以下になります。

```
ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RegexNotFoundError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:815, in YoutubeDL.__handle_extraction_exceptions..wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    814 try:
--> 815     return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    816 except GeoRestrictedError as e:

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:836, in YoutubeDL.__extract_info(self, url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
    834 @__handle_extraction_exceptions
    835 def __extract_info(self, url, ie, download, extra_info, process):
--> 836     ie_result = ie.extract(url)
    837     if ie_result is None:  # Finished already (backwards compatibility; listformats and friends should be moved here)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py:534, in InfoExtractor.extract(self, url)
    533 self.initialize()
--> 534 ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
    535 if self._x_forwarded_for_ip:

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py:1794, in YoutubeIE._real_extract(self, url)
   1782 owner_profile_url = microformat.get('ownerProfileUrl')
   1784 info = {
   1785     'id': video_id,
   1786     'title': self._live_title(video_title) if is_live else video_title,
   1787     'formats': formats,
   1788     'thumbnails': thumbnails,
   1789     'description': video_description,
   1790     'upload_date': unified_strdate(
   1791         microformat.get('uploadDate')
   1792         or search_meta('uploadDate')),
   1793     'uploader': video_details['author'],
-> 1794     'uploader_id': self._search_regex(r'/(?:channel|user)/([^/?&#]+)', owner_profile_url, 'uploader id') if owner_profile_url else None,
   1795     'uploader_url': owner_profile_url,
   1796     'channel_id': channel_id,
   1797     'channel_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/' + channel_id if channel_id else None,
   1798     'duration': duration,
   1799     'view_count': int_or_none(
   1800         video_details.get('viewCount')
   1801         or microformat.get('viewCount')
   1802         or search_meta('interactionCount')),
   1803     'average_rating': float_or_none(video_details.get('averageRating')),
   1804     'age_limit': 18 if (
   1805         microformat.get('isFamilySafe') is False
   1806         or search_meta('isFamilyFriendly') == 'false'
   1807         or search_meta('og:restrictions:age') == '18+') else 0,
   1808     'webpage_url': webpage_url,
   1809     'categories': [category] if category else None,
   1810     'tags': keywords,
   1811     'is_live': is_live,
   1812 }
   1814 pctr = try_get(
   1815     player_response,
   1816     lambda x: x['captions']['playerCaptionsTracklistRenderer'], dict)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py:1012, in InfoExtractor._search_regex(self, pattern, string, name, default, fatal, flags, group)
   1011 elif fatal:
-> 1012     raise RegexNotFoundError('Unable to extract %s' % _name)
   1013 else:

RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DownloadError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 6
      3 import youtube_dl
      5 with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s'}) as youtube:
----> 6     youtube.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RNltA11uim4'])

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:2068, in YoutubeDL.download(self, url_list)
   2065 for url in url_list:
   2066     try:
   2067         # It also downloads the videos
-> 2068         res = self.extract_info(
   2069             url, force_generic_extractor=self.params.get('force_generic_extractor', False))
   2070     except UnavailableVideoError:
   2071         self.report_error('unable to download video')

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:808, in YoutubeDL.extract_info(self, url, download, ie_key, extra_info, process, force_generic_extractor)
    804     if not ie.working():
    805         self.report_warning('The program functionality for this site has been marked as broken, '
    806                             'and will probably not work.')
--> 808     return self.__extract_info(url, ie, download, extra_info, process)
    809 else:
    810     self.report_error('no suitable InfoExtractor for URL %s' % url)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:824, in YoutubeDL.__handle_extraction_exceptions..wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    822     self.report_error(msg)
    823 except ExtractorError as e:  # An error we somewhat expected
--> 824     self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
    825 except MaxDownloadsReached:
    826     raise

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:628, in YoutubeDL.report_error(self, message, tb)
    626     _msg_header = 'ERROR:'
    627 error_message = '%s %s' % (_msg_header, message)
--> 628 self.trouble(error_message, tb)

File ~/workspace/orcas_proj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py:598, in YoutubeDL.trouble(self, message, tb)
    596     else:
    597         exc_info = sys.exc_info()
--> 598     raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
    599 self._download_retcode = 1

DownloadError: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Comment: エラーに出ている通り、最新版への更新を試すか開発元に報告すべき内容かと思います。

Comment: [youtube_dl - PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/) は古いようですので [yt-dlp -PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/yt-dlp/#usage-and-options) に切り替えてみては？ [yt-dlpをPythonから実行する](https://note.com/note_fumi/n/n72b755dac88a), [pythonでYouTubeをダウンロードするyt-dlpのコピペコード14本まとめ](https://diy-programming.site/youtube/download/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。[yt-dlp]に切り替えたところ、うまくいきました。
これからは、[yt-dlp]を利用するようにします。助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

教えていただいた、https://diy-programming.site/youtube/download/より、

```
pip install yt-dlp
```

で、インストール。

```
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL
with YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    result = ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQkdpQdVa7w'])
```

で、ダウンロードできました。